# PyCharm autocomplete

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

I'm completely new to Python and PyCharm and I cannot figure out why PyCharm doesn't auto-completes very simple cases such as:

```
import pickle

pickle.dum[control+space or control+shift+space results nothing here]
```

I have PyCharm 2.6.2 and Python 2.7.1. What's wrong?

**Add:**

I'm on Mac OS 10.7.3

Comment: can you run python projects from pycharm? I dunno it works fine for me and i didnt do any kind of special setup...

Comment: yes, I ran several helloworld-like examples

Answer (score 13):

Can't reproduce. Make sure you have a valid Python interpreter configured for the project. Also try `File` | `Invalidate Caches`.

[image: pickle]

Comment: Thank you CrazyCoder, cache invalidation didn't help and if I can run simple python scripts and see their output doesn't this mean that I properly configured interpreter? or something can still be missing in project configuration?

**add:** autocomplete works for "pickle" in import, but not as at your sceenshot

Comment: Project interpreter can be different from the one used in the run configuration.

Comment: I've checked it on Mac 10.8.2 with system default Python 2.7.2 and it also works fine. View | Quick Documentation should show where the completion is taken from: http://o7.no/P3t3Mg.

Comment: thanks a lot! after playing with interpreter and project settings I got it working

Comment: Worked for me trying to get praw completion and documentation working after installing in-IDE. Surprising that cache invalidation was necessary, though. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

My experience is if you turn ON the File -> Power-Save Mode, all background tasks will be stopped, including the Auto-Complete task. 
So you can try turning off the Power-Save Mode.

Comment: thanks a lot, dear, Its really help me get back my autocomplete feature with CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with a virtualenv and on it install all you project dependencies and the go to pycharm preferences/Project Interpreter and it will update your project dependencies.

[Project Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9X4L.png)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the projector interpreter and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me, too.
But all the previous answers don't solve my issue.

The weird thing is when I am coding, it will pump out the autocomplete for me. But once I leave the autocomplete mode, I cannot reproduce the autocomplete by typing `Ctrl` + `Space`.

So the work I already surveyed are

1. Make sure the config(e.g., virtualenv) is right in Pycharm
2. Make sure Pycharm can show autocomplete
3. Make sure I am not in the `Power Safe Mode`

Finally I solved this just because my shortcut of switch language in the Mac is also `Ctrl` + `Space`, so it's kind of override my shortcut in the Pycharm. I change the shortcut in the Pycharm by changing in `Pycharm-> Preference-> Keymap-> Main menu-> Code-> Completion ->Basic`

Then the problem is solved