# PyCharm does not auto-compete code from SymPy library

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, sympy

I'm using PyCharm and it does not seem to auto-complete code from the library SymPy.

I am using that library via anaconda, and if I write its code explicitly it works, but PyCharm won't auto-complete it.

For example, SymPy offers a function called `symbols()`. If I write `x = symb` I would expect it to complete it, but it doesn't.

Also, I am using this interpeter (I have only anaconda installed on my computer):
[Used Interpeter Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvaQ3.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517535/pycharm-autocomplete

Comment: I saw that post and it did not help me.

Comment: Deleting the cache worked for me when Pycharm stopped autocompleting things

Comment: How do you import SymPy?

Comment: `from sympy import *`

Comment: also, if I import as `import sympy` and try to use the functions like `sympy.symbols()` it does not auto-complete.